# ACCESS permission error in /data folder

Tags: android

I am trying to open a file in /data folder from native Android code.

```
#define FILE_PATH "/data/sdata.txt"
int fptr = open(FILE_PATH, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_APPEND, 0665);
if (fptr < 0) {
    logE("File open failed (%s)", strerror(errno));
}
```

The open command is failing always with the log:

```
File open failed (Permission denied)
```

Kindly suggest a possible way to fix the problem.

Comment: have you define this : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: This is the native code (library), so there is no manifest here. Adding permission would be valid if it was an Android app.

Comment: What do you mean by `native code (library)`? And from where you execute this code, if it wasn't an Android app?

Comment: This is the library for Radio Interface Layer (RIL). Android telephony Framework calls the methods of this library to interact with modem.